# Is there a way to identify a variable declaration kind using the Compiler API?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I'm using the Compiler API to search for some structures written (majorly) in JavaScript. Is there any way to infer whether a variable declaration is using a `const` (or const assertions), `var` or `let` statement? For example, in this code:

```
const a = 1;
```

I can see a `flags` property with value `2` inside the VariableDeclarationList node when using [AST Explorer](https://astexplorer.net/) but when I'm parsing using the Compiler API this property assumes a different value. I tried to compare the `flags` property with `ts.NodeFlags.Const` but it always results in false. I'm using Typescript 4.4.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can see a flags property with value 2 inside the VariableDeclarationList node when using AST Explorer but when I'm parsing using the Compiler API this property assumes a different value. I tried to compare the flags property with ts.NodeFlags.Const but it always results in false.

That's exactly how you do this. Make sure to check the flags using [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_AND):

```
const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile("file.ts", "const a = 1;");
const varStmt = sourceFile.statements[0] as ts.VariableStatement;
const isConst = (varStmt.declarationList.flags & ts.NodeFlags.Const) !== 0;

console.log(isConst); // true
```

Comment: It worked, thanks!